# regarding the relation of close() and read()

Tags: c, process, pipe

```
int main()
{
    char *msg="hello";
    char buff[MAX];
    int p[2];
    pipe(p);
    int i,pid=fork();
    if(pid>0){
        //close(p[1]);
        read(p[0],buff, MAX);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("child exiting\n");
    }
}
```

Why does the above code end up blocking ? But then if we remove the comment and place

```
close(p[1])
```

then why does the code end immediately ?

Comment: It appears strange to me that this nice question has received a downvote

Answer (score 2):

Once you create a pipe, it gets four ends:

- A reading end `p[0]` in the parent process
- A writing end `p[1]` in the parent process
- A reading end `p[0]` in the child process
- A writing end `p[1]` in the child process

UNIX will not deliver `EOF` to the reader unless both writing ends have been closed, because it knows that the pipe is still writeable.

When the child process exits, it closes both ends of the pipe on its side. However, the parent still has one writeable end open, so reading from the pipe blocks instead of delivering an `EOF` to the parent. That is why UNIX manual instructs to close the unused ends of the pipe right away:

> An application that uses `pipe(2)` and `fork(2)` should use suitable `close(2)` calls to close unnecessary duplicate file descriptors; this ensures that end-of-file and `SIGPIPE`/`EPIPE` are delivered when appropriate.

Here is an example of how to make your program not block without closing `p[1]` on the parent side:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* write_pipe(void* pp) {
    int* p = (int*)pp;
    char msg[] = "Hello from another thread!";
    write(p[1], msg, sizeof(msg));
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[100];
    int p[2];
    pipe(p);
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0){
        pthread_t thread1;
        pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, &write_pipe, (void *)p);
        read(p[0],buff, 100);
        printf("%s\n", buff);
        printf("parent exiting\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("child exiting\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above writes to the writing end of the pipe from a thread within the parent process, instead of writing to it from the child process. This is a legitimate use of a pipe, too, illustrating why UNIX cannot deliver `EOF` unless the parent's writing end of the pipe is closed.

Comment: In my original code if do a close in child process and wait in parent process , still the parent gets blocked . But you told that The call of read on the pipe is blocking. It will not complete until one of two things happen:

Some data becomes available for read to return to the caller, or
The pipe is closed

Comment: @AchyutaAich I'm sorry, I did not understand your question at first. I'll try to come up with an example that uses the unclosed end on the parent's side.

Answer (score 0):

Read is a blocking call and it returns only when it receives EOF . If you wont close the write end of the pipe, read end wont get the EOF and hence,program will remain blocked